# Conditional Format to change font color in row based on cell input

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I'm developing an aircraft tracking log.

Is there a formula or conditional format or VBA that could gray out the FONT (change all font to black) of an entire row once the ATA is entered in a cell?

I looked all over the internet and can't find anything I am looking to accomplish.

I attached a snapshot of the spreadsheet.

[Aircraft log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INB7w.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try-

```
=$G2<>""
```

And apply to `=$2:$500` If you want to apply to only few cells of row then try apply to `=$A$2:$F$500` but formatting formula is same `=$G2<>""`

[image]

[image]